# error " org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: Invalid IRI value "

Tags: graphdb

I have problem when i try to import my RDF file

> org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: Invalid IRI value

as in the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcx6L.png

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have error in the turtle file. One possible workaround is to disable the stop on error when uploading the file - http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/loading-data-using-the-workbench.html#import-settings which will upload try to upload all valid triples and skip all errors.

Answer (score 1):

Always validate your RDF files before loading, eg with Jena `riot`

Comment: An online validator identified the error for me. Would be nice if the errors from GraphDB were a bit more informative in these cases, thereby not having to look for a third-party tool.